# how to make Ubuntu prevent port scan

Tags: networking, 15.10, portscan

I am running Ubuntu 15.10. My Hosting provider constantly keeps telling me that my system is blocked because there were port scanning requests on the hosting server from my IP.

How can I prevent this from happening? Or is there a way to find out what application in my system is triggering the scan?

When I'm running Windows 10 which is on dual boot, this issue does not occur.

Here is the log from the Hosting provier

```
lfd - *Port Scan* detected from 162.75.58.238 (IN/India/nsg-static-138.58.75.162-airtel.com). 6 hits in the last 74 seconds

Nov 30 13:04:44 gins lfd[577239]: *Port Scan* detected from 162.75.58.138 (IN/India/nsg-static-138.58.75.162-airtel.com). 6 hits in the last 74 seconds - *Blocked in csf* for 3600 secs [PS_LIMIT]
```

Comment: How do you know that it doesn't occour when using Windows 10?

Comment: Port scanning on which server?  Ubuntu out of the box does not perform port scanning.  Do you have any additional network software installed?

Comment: Can you confirm that you are on a fixed (public) IP address, on your ADSL (or cable) connection to your ISP? (Or is your/this server hosted somewhere?) *Without this detail the question is not answerable.*

Comment: @mchid: on windows i can access my hosted website for days without incidents. But on my linux box any given day, i get blocked out 2-3 times.

Comment: @tripleee: port scanning on the remote server where i'm hosting a website. i do not recall installing any network software .

Comment: @david6: i am not on a fixed IP. it dynamically changes every 12 hours i guess. my hosted server is in the US. I am accessing the servers from India.

Comment: So where's the scanning coming from?   From your IP/computer to your remote server run by a hosting company?

Comment: It is possible that *some other party* (with 'your' IP address) is doing port scanning. Then you again get assigned that IP address. **Can you get a fixed IP address assigned?**

Comment: @david6: no i have to pay extra for a fixed ip

Comment: Typically, YES. It depends on your ISP/provider. Try 'shopping around' for a hosting provider that has fixed-IP ..

Comment: You may check you own machine using `wireshark`, How do you connect the server, some multi-protocol clients check for available ones 22/SFTP, 989-990/FTPS then 21/FTP, may be that counted as scan, see if the client tool have option to forrce specific protocol/port. If you share Internet connection (from router or your pc) then you better check other devices too, a malware is also expected (including phones).

Answer (score 0):

The key element here is:

```
 *Blocked in csf* for 3600 secs [PS_LIMIT]
```

You will need to login on your cpanel (hosting server) configuration page and look for [PS_LIMIT], it is probably set to default which minimum (5 I guess). This parameter set the port scan limitation and you can increase that. this will stop the complaints from your hosting company for now as temporary solution.

Lets look for permanent solution here and regardless I have a quick question for you here.

Are you running any server application from your PC?

Answer to the above question will give us better clue because I am pretty sure your PC application (such as DB or webserver) is causing this and LFD is likely misinterpreting your traffic as port scan.

pls also check:

```
   /var/log/lfd.log
```

and post the relevant findings (maybe grep "Blocked IP").

Comment: I think i have apache webserver running on my laptop

Comment: there is no log called lfd.log in /var/log

Comment: lfd log must be there somewhere as you posted from hosting provider it says "lfd" as you can see and if it not in /var/log must be somewehere else

Comment: so you are running apache, you are experiencing a false positive type issue where your activity or login is interpreted by LFD as port scan. Go to csf.conf and increase the 2 parameters "PS_INTERVAL" and "PS_LIMIT" as suggested above.